# Access Denied from S3 explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-s3, aws-toolkit

I'm evaluating S3 GUI alternatives. Starting with the S3 Explorer of the AWS Toolkit for VS Code, I want to display the contents of a bucket. I created a string object using the Java SDK, and I can see it using `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket`. But when I expand the S3 section in the explorer view of the AWS Toolkit I get

> Failed to load resources (click for logs)

and in the log file

> ...
> code: 'AccessDenied',
> region: null,
> time: 2023-11-28T14:26:07.355Z,
> requestId: 'CB5GVTG1Q0TXJTWC',
> extendedRequestId: '65sml50+g5jZ8PposW0TVODKc57tHhyKbxZqvfeBOj6nwKo8saDferYFTK7oY/EyLPPHbuvRIWE=',
> cfId: undefined,
> statusCode: 403,
> ...

I noticed that the region is `null`. For `aws configure` I gave a default region. How to do that in VS Code? What else could I be missing?

**EDIT**: Here's a screen of the Explorer view:

[image: Explorer view]

This is the content of .aws\config:

```
[default]
region = eu-central-1
```

And .aws\credentials looks like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = MYACCESSKEYID
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

which I understand are also used by the AWS CLI that works as expected. This is from the log file:

```
2023-12-01 14:02:32 [ERROR]: [AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at constructor.extractError (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:42:10391)
    at constructor.callListeners (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:21245)
    at constructor.emit (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:20954)
    at constructor.emitEvent (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:6815)
    at constructor.I (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:2360)
    at G.runTo (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:53:1767)
    at c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:53:1979
    at constructor.<anonymous> (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:2571)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:6870)
    at constructor.callListeners (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:21349)
    at constructor.emit (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:20954)
    at constructor.emitEvent (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:6815)
    at constructor.I (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:2360)
    at G.runTo (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:53:1767)
    at c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:53:1979
    at constructor.<anonymous> (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:2571)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:6870)
    at constructor.callListeners (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:21349)
    at I (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:39:21130)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (c:\Users\siggi\.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.100.0\dist\src\main.js:32:41916)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)] {
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  region: null,
  time: 2023-12-01T13:02:32.993Z,
  requestId: '2T3HKNESNHYQY6TC',
  extendedRequestId: 'khcp9BedKWf28q/6iIVB+3M3EBFVT7bblfFmfRFWWSqOchCrR3QKozHCLB6Y085zoKQCK7r2PXw=',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 14.865983225304946
}
```

Comment: What S3 permissions do the credentials you have supplied to the VS Code extension have?

Comment: I would say they have the default permissions. I use the same credentials for the Java SDK, AWS CLI and the AWS Toolkit. They were generated using the Cloud Foundry CLI: ```cf create-service-key bucketname keyname```

Comment: There are no default AWS permissions (well, "not permitted" is the default). I don't know what Cloud Foundry does in terms of IAM roles and policies but you should check you're actually using the credentials you think you are using and perhaps review CloudTrail logs (assuming they're enabled) to see what actually happened (which credentials were used and which API action was invoked that failed).

Comment: The GUI is somebody else's requirement, and I won;'t go into CloudTrail logs to get this one to work. I'll be looking for a different tool. As a final attempt: I can see in VS Code that the plugin connects successfully to AWS. I also installed the AWS Toolkit for IntelliJ Idea CE and I'm seeing "Error Loading Resources (S3: AccessDenied)". Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Check that you can list S3 buckets

> I can see it using `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket`

Does `aws s3 ls` (*not* `aws s3 ls s3://...`) list your buckets? AWS Toolkit needs permission to list all buckets. You may have permission to list the *contents* of a specific bucket, but cannot list all buckets.

## Check your AWS region

When you connect the Explorer in AWS Toolkit, the `Connected with ...` label shows which profile is selected:

[image]

You can click the `Connected with ...` label, or run the vscode command `AWS: Connect to AWS`, to list all credentials that AWS Toolkit found, and where it found them.

If your profile in `~/.aws/` has a `region=...` item, AWS Toolkit will use that. Else it defaults to `us-east-1`.

[image]

Comment: I have updated the post. I tried to reconnect with the VSCode command, but it's still not working.

Comment: @siggi I updated the post. Please check that `aws s3 ls` (_without_ specifying a bucket) lists all buckets.

Comment: that command gives me "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied", which is actually helpful. 
This might still be of interest for some, however, I was focussing on an easy setup. 
I won't go into this any further, because I found a different tool (Cyberduck), which only had to be configured with the URL that has the bucket name as subdomain: myaccesskeyid@mybucket.amazonaws.com. 

Now, I assume that granting the user access to the ListBucket resource should get the AWS Toolkit to work.